# python can't append a string to each element of a tuple using join

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I tried to append a string to each element string in a tuple using join,

```
str_tup = ('country', 'town')
fields = ('_outlier'.join(key) for key in str_tup)

for key in fields:
    print(key)
```

I got

```
c_outliero_outlieru_outliern_outliert_outlierr_outliery
t_outliero_outlierw_outliern
```

instead of

```
country_outlier
town_outlier
```

I am wondering how to resolve the issue, using a generator here trying to save memory.

Comment: sry, I have modified the op to clarify the misunderstandings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `join(x)` function concatenates an iterable(e.g. a list) of items, placing `x` in between every item. What you are looking for is simple concatenation:

```
str_tup = ('country', 'town')
fields = (key + '_outlier' for key in str_tup)

for key in fields:
    print(key)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 3.6+, I suggest you to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) to build the generator, which are very beautiful and optimized. They really deserve to be known and widely used. Here is my proposal:

```
str_tup = ('country', 'town')
fields = (f'{s}_outlier' for s in str_tup)

for key in fields:
    print(key)
# country_outlier
# town_outlier
```